# Paragraph Yields a Vertical scrollbar

Tags: internet-explorer, scrollbar, paragraph

The code below yields a vertical scrollbar in IE. Chrome works OK, but I need to use IE because of that doggone fakepath problem. The code is for a local HTML5 video player. The <p> tag can be changed to <div> with formatted top or bottom margins, & it works fine in IE. But, I'm curious why IE compiles the paragraph tag so the screen requires the scrollbar. Can one use the <p> tag, or does one have to settle for a <div> with formatted top or bottom margins?

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="width:265px">
<hr>
<output id="list">No videos selected!</output>
<hr>
<p id="playing"></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#playing {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

A little cheating but hiding the scrollbar should be enough.

Comment: It's a good cheat, but I need the scrollbar for later, in case the list of selected videos overflows the bottom. Thanks for your answer, though.

Comment: You could use Javascript to count the elements in the list and if it's over your set value to change overflow to scroll-x :)